# How can I cross out a node in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I would like to indicate that a node should be there, but is currently lacking in the process.
Intuitively I would like to cross it out as shown in below image (now done manually in Paint):

[image]

Is there a node attribute in Graphviz that I can use for this?

Comment: I should have mentioned that "neato -n2" is documented in the FAQ and that the gvpr program is replacing edge routing with a straight line from edge start to edge end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [the answer of sroush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62491401/1256347) gives me the exact output I need, it requires that I understand how to introduce `gvpr` in my workflow which will take a bit of time.

In the meantime I came up with a `dot` only approach, which approximates crossing out a node sufficiently for my purpose.

In below graph I would like to cross out the node `Some process`:

```
digraph graphname {
    rankdir=LR
    node [fillcolor="lightblue3", style="filled"]
        a
        c
        d
        b [label="Some\nprocess"]
    a -> b -> c
    a -> d -> c
    {rank=same a;d}
}
```

[image]

To do so I change:

- the nodestyle of the `Some process` node to have a [diagonal](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:gradientangle) hard [gradient](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:colorList)
- use a [HTML-like label](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) to strikethrough the text
- Make the `fontcolor` and node outline a shade of gray

```
digraph graphname {
    rankdir=LR
    node [fillcolor="lightblue3", style="filled"]
        a
        c
        d
    node [fillcolor="lightblue3;0.5:white", style="filled", fontcolor="gray50", color="gray50", gradientangle=100]
        b [label=<<s>Some<br/>process</s>>]
    a -> b -> c
    a -> d -> c
    {rank=same a;d}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't find an attribute or node shape to do what you want, but here are two ways to do it:

1. build an image outside of Graphviz (with the text and the X) and use the image attribute to use the image as the node (yes, a pain if you want to do this frequently):

   b [image="myB.png"]
2. For every X'd out node, add 2 new edges from .ne to .sw and .nw to .se (see below) Each with this (new) attribute: straightline=1.  Then run this command:

```
dot -Tdot Xout2.gv |gvpr -f straightline.gvpr -c | neato -n2 -Tpng >out.png
```

Where this is straightline.gvpr:

```
E[straightline==1]{
  int i, n;
  string pt[int];
  double x1, y1, x2, y2, xI1, yI1, xI2, yI2;

  n=split($.pos, pt, " ");

  for (i=0;i<=1;i++){
    if (match(pt[i],"e,")>=0){
      print ("//  BEFORE: ", pt[i]);
      pt[n-1]=substr(pt[i],2);
      print ("//  AFTER: ", pt[i]);
      pt[i]=pt[i+1];
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<=1;i++){
    if (match(pt[i],"s,")>=0){
      pt[0]=substr(pt[i],2);
    }
  }

  sscanf (pt[0], "%f,%f", &x1, &y1);
  sscanf (pt[n-1], "%f,%f", &x2, &y2);
  xI1=x1+(x2-x1)*.3;
  yI1=y1+(y2-y1)*.3;
  xI2=x1+(x2-x1)*.7;
  yI2=y1+(y2-y1)*.7;

  $.pos=sprintf("%s %.3f,%.3f %.3f,%.3f %s", pt[0], xI1, yI1, xI2, yI2, pt[n-1]);
}
```

[image]

From this input:

```
digraph X{
  graph [outputorder=edgefirst]

  b [ label="X me"]
  a -> b -> c 
  a -> d
  d -> c

  e -> f 
  g -> i -> k

  edge [color="#ff000080" penwidth=2]  // note translucent color
  b:ne -> b:sw  [straightline=1]
  b:se -> b:nw  [straightline=1]

  edge [color="green" penwidth=2]
  e:n -> e:s  [straightline=1]
  f:w -> f:se [straightline=1]

  edge [color="orange" penwidth=2]
  g:n -> g:se [dir=back straightline=1]
  edge [color="blue" penwidth=2]
  g:n -> g:sw [dir=back straightline=1]
  i:e -> i:w [dir=none straightline=1]
  k -> k:s [dir=both straightline=1]
}
```

Sorry, convoluted, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite creative. I've never looked into `gvpr`, perhaps I should. In the meantime I found a different, lighter workaround (will post it in a minute).